# Java - Converting bytes to megabytes

Tags: java, math, memory

I have the following code here:

```
long memoryUsedOnStartup = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() -
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

and I'm using it for some statistical stuff in my program, but this returns it in kilobytes. Is there any reliable way to convert this to megabytes?

EDIT: It returns it in bytes, but I still need it in megabytes...

Comment: How many kilobytes to a megabyte? (hint, it's not 1000 :P)

Comment: 1024... so times/divide by 1024? Sorry if the answer is obvious, my math is horrible.

Comment: @Logan `1MB = 1024KB`. Which means that to convert KB to MB, you need to divide the number of KBs by 1024.

Comment: What I've got is it gets the memory used in bytes, then I divide it by 1024 twice, and that seems to give me the correct amount. I'll settle with that as the answer.

Comment: Doesn't the function return bytes ?

Comment: Actually, 1 Megabyte is 1,000,000 bytes. 1 Mebibyte is 1,048,576 bytes. A  lot of people, like me, grew up with factors of 2^10 (1024) but that's  incorrect usage of SI units. For RAM, factors of 1024 are still common but SI units are not incorrect. For disk storage, very few manufacturers quote in factors of 1024 (because the outcome is lower) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1 Kilobyte (KB) -> 2^10 = 1,024 Bytes
>
> 1 Megabyte (MB) -> 2^20 = 1,048,576 Bytes = 1,024 Kilobytes (KB)

[public long freeMemory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory--)

> Return: an approximation to the total amount of memory currently
>   available for future allocated objects, measured in bytes.

[public long totalMemory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory--)

> Returns: the total amount of memory currently available for current
>   and future objects, measured in bytes.

So when you are calculating `memoryUsedOnStartup` it's in bytes. If you want to get the result in **Megabytes** then you need to divide it by `(1024 * 1024)`

Answer (score -2):

To convert bytes to MB below is the formula.

```
bytes/1e+6 = Mb
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private static final long  MB = 1024L * 1024L;

 public static long KBToMB(long KB) 
 {
    return KB / MB;
 }
```

Comment: That is not the correct way. Check this with some real values. Besides that you should not uppercase the function name and KB